# How to use a response filter in Jersey that is executed in all exceptional scenarios, too

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, servlet-filters

I'd like to add a filter in Jersey that adds some standard HTTP header to all responses from the server.

If I use a javax.servlet.Filter, it is only executed for "normal" responses. If there is an uncatched exception that generates its response via an error mapper, the filter is not executed.

If I use one of Jersey's ContainerResponseFilters, it does not work, if another javax filter throws an exception.

How can I add a filter (or maybe listener, error mapper, whatever) that is ALWAYS executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *javax.servlet.Filter*, just make sure it is the first on in the filter chain (by simply adding it at first place in your web.xml). Second thing you have to make sure is that the request header is added before the further chain is called.

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException { 
   // add header here
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```